# How to edit files inside of docker containers for development?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm creating my Typo3 develop instance with docker containers. And in order to understand what I'm doing so I can understand completely my workflow I'm trying to keep it simple and go step by step to a more advanced instance.
This is my docker-compose file.

This mounted volumes are fine, they are being mounter, their permissions are for root.

What I do is to go inside of the container and set users and groups as www-data in order to access these files from the browser and then on the host set my user as the owner so I can edit them from the host.

But is this right? is this the correct approach? Because I have seen some scripts where all you need to do is to set www-data inside of the container, so I wonder why the permissions on my case are root.

```
version: "3"
services:
  typo3:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./fileadmin:/var/www/html/fileadmin
      - ./typo3conf:/var/www/html/typo3conf
      - ./uploads:/var/www/html/uploads
    networks:
      - backend
  database:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command:
      - --character-set-server=utf8
      - --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
      - "MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT}"
    networks:
      - backend
volumes:
  database:
  fileadmin:
  typo3conf:
  uploads:
networks:
  backend:
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Docker image for TYPO3 CMS
# Copyright (C) 2016-2020  Martin Helmich <martin@helmich.me>
#                          and contributors <https://github.com/martin-helmich/docker-typo3/graphs/contributors>
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

FROM php:7.4-apache-buster
LABEL maintainer="Martin Helmich <typo3@martin-helmich.de>"

# Install TYPO3
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        wget \
# Configure PHP
        libxml2-dev libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
# Install required 3rd party tools
        graphicsmagick && \
# Configure extensions
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-libdir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg --with-freetype && \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mysqli soap gd zip opcache intl pgsql pdo_pgsql && \
    echo 'always_populate_raw_post_data = -1\nmax_execution_time = 240\nmax_input_vars = 1500\nupload_max_filesize = 32M\npost_max_size = 32M' > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/typo3.ini && \
# Configure Apache as needed
    a2enmod rewrite && \
    apt-get clean && \
    apt-get -y purge \
        libxml2-dev libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        zlib1g-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /usr/src/*

RUN cd /var/www/html && \
    wget -O download.tar.gz https://get.typo3.org/10.4.19 && \
    echo "8eb40d02954ffe431c8a41420e4d73d9e0a702714960ecca89162d87ca0e4118 download.tar.gz" > download.tar.gz.sum && \
    sha256sum -c download.tar.gz.sum && \
    tar -xzf download.tar.gz && \
    rm download.* && \
    ln -s typo3_src-* typo3_src && \
    ln -s typo3_src/index.php && \
    ln -s typo3_src/typo3 && \
    cp typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess .htaccess && \
    mkdir typo3temp && \
    mkdir typo3conf && \
    mkdir fileadmin && \
    mkdir uploads && \
    touch FIRST_INSTALL && \
    chown -R www-data. .

# Configure volumes
VOLUME /var/www/html/fileadmin
VOLUME /var/www/html/typo3conf
VOLUME /var/www/html/typo3temp
VOLUME /var/www/html/uploads
```

Comment: "*their permissions are www-data*" - on the host (your machine), or in the container?  Typically the files on your host/local machine are owned by *you*, eg they're somewhere under your home dir.  You don't need to change ownership (or permissions).  Once they are mapped into the container, ownership *in the container* 
 will be (automatically) set according to the Dockerfile/compose config, but typically you shouldn't have to worry about that at all either.  Why are you changing ownership in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the question. Permissions after running docker-compose up -d are root everywhere

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, for me, I usually use next 2 options:

- Enter into the container with `docker exec -it $your_container_name /bin/bash`, then install vim or nano in container.
- Modern IDE/editor provides direct access to container, so you could develop/edit files in container just like you are doing it in local.
  E.g. VSCode afford "remote containers plugin", after enable it, you could just in your host pc to development the files in container.
  Details refers to [Developing inside a Container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers)

Comment: Thanks, yes, I install nano on the containers just in case. But the idea is to have an instance of the project for developing so I need to do it from the local machine with my preferred IDE and rest of the tools.
I use Sublime and VS code, I will check their extensions, that may work.